How to get the 3D cursor to align with an edge when using Cursor to Selected
I swear this used to be a feature by default and maybe my preferences got screwed. When using the option of cursor to selected with an edge selected how do I make the cursor copy the rotation as well like in the image?


Snap Cursor to Selection operator never used to do that as far as I can remember. Maybe you used some add-on for that?  It's definitely possible to write an operator for that using Python.

You can interactively position the cursor using  Shift  +  RMB  dragging. It's also possible to use snapping functionality while in that operation by holding  Ctrl   as well. So if you set snapping options to Edge Center together with Align Rotation to Target, you can do that.


I am holding  Shift  , then hold  RMB  and start dragging and then press and hold  Ctrl  for snapping in the GIF.
